# Get a parent node of a node in xml- nokogiri-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the XML data:

```
  <questionpaper>
   <question1>
      <id>540<id>
      <content>....</content>
   </question1>
   <question2>
      <id>550<id>
      <content>....</content>
   </question2>
   .
   .
   .
   <question10>
      <id>560<id>
      <content>....</content>
   </question10>
```

If i give 540 i,e id, I should get its parent node that is question1. I'm using nokogiri and tried

```
   @qpid = Qpaper.find(params[:id])
   file = File.open(@qpid.qpaper_file)
   xml = Nokogiri::XML(file)
   quest = xml.search("//id[text()= '#{params[:qno]}']")     //params[:qno] gives id
   render text: quest.parent
```

It is giving error

```
  undefined method `parent' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:0xe603890>
```

Please help me solving it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quest` contains a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`, not a single `Node`.  Call parent on one of the nodes in the node set instead:

```
quest = xml.search("//id[text()= '#{params[:qno]}']")
render text: quest.first.parent
```